# Getting only one id from duplicate ids (all having diffrent values) & permanently updating the unique id with only one value (applying condition)

Tags: mysql, sql

I can't seem to solve this. I need to update this in table permanently. I need to apply 2 conditions here -

(1) when the same id has both values as 'Bachelor's' and 'Masters', I need to have the id only once and it should contain the degree as 'Bachelor's'.

(2) when the same id has values as 'Bachelor's' and 'Masters' and 'PHD', I need to have the id only once and it should contain the degree as 'Masters'.

```
id         degree 
1           bachelor
2           master
3           bachelor
1           master
2           bachelor 
2           phd
```

I want result like this -

```
1        bachelor
2        master 
3        bachelor
```

Want it to be permanently updated in table, so that I can join it to other table.

Comment: what did you try? what is the problem you are facing? are you facing problem in removing entries from table or updating any specific entry?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first I tried to do what you described, and I did this

```
drop table test7;

create table test7 (
id_num number,
education varchar(25)
);

insert into test7 values(1,'bachelor');
insert into test7 values(2,'masters');
insert into test7 values(3,'bachelor');
insert into test7 values(1,'masters');
insert into test7 values(2,'bachelor');
insert into test7 values(2,'phd');

-- this finds those id numbers that have duplicates
--select count(id_num),id_num from test7 group by id_num having count(id_num) > 1;

-- this shows the duplicate ids, their id number, and their education
--select c.multi,c.id_num,t.education from (select count(id_num) multi,id_num from test7 group by id_num having count(id_num) > 1) c left join test7 t on c.id_num=t.id_num;

-- this finds the distinct id number that has 2 duplicates
--select distinct id_num from (select c.multi,c.id_num,t.education from (select count(id_num) multi,id_num from test7 group by id_num having count(id_num) > 1) c left join test7 t on c.id_num=t.id_num) where multi = 2;

-- when there are two records with the same id, get rid of the masters one
delete from test7 where id_num = (select distinct id_num from (select c.multi,c.id_num,t.education from (select count(id_num) multi,id_num from test7 group by id_num having count(id_num) > 1) c left join test7 t on c.id_num=t.id_num) where multi = 2) and education = 'masters'; 

-- when there are 3 records with the same id, get rid of bachelor and phd
delete from test7 where id_num = (select distinct id_num from (select c.multi,c.id_num,t.education from (select count(id_num) multi,id_num from test7 group by id_num having count(id_num) > 1) c left join test7 t on c.id_num=t.id_num) where multi = 3) and education = 'bachelor' or education = 'phd'; 

    select * from test7;

    ID_NUM EDUCATION               
---------- -------------------------
         1 bachelor                 
         2 masters  
         3 bachelor
```

This works for what you have described, but it doesn't allow much for variations.

However, normally when you want to join tables on id numbers, you want distinct id/value pairs, so I added a solution that would work for that as well...

```
drop table temp;
drop table test6;
drop sequence temp_id_seq;


create table test6 (
id_num number,
education varchar(25)
);

insert into test6 values(1,'bachelor');
insert into test6 values(2,'master');
insert into test6 values(3,'bachelor');
insert into test6 values(1,'master');
insert into test6 values(2,'bachelor');
insert into test6 values(2,'phd');

create table temp (
temp_id number,
education varchar(25)
);

create sequence temp_id_seq
minvalue 1
maxvalue 100000
start with 1
increment by 1
nocycle;

create or replace trigger created_temp_id
before insert on temp
for each row
begin
:new.temp_id := temp_id_seq.nextval;
end;
/

insert into temp(education) select distinct education from test6;

select * from temp;

delete from test6;

insert into test6 select * from temp;

select * from test6;

-- which results in this:

    ID_NUM EDUCATION               
---------- -------------------------
         1 master                   
         2 phd                      
         3 bachelor
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT a.id,
 CASE 
  WHEN FIND_IN_SET('bachelor, master', a.groups) > 0 THEN 'bachelor'
  WHEN FIND_IN_SET('bachelor, master, phd', a.groups) > 0 THEN 'master'
 END AS grouping
FROM(
 SELECT
  id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(degree ORDER BY degree ASC SEPARATOR ', ') groups
 FROM `tablename`
 GROUP BY id) a
```